# Emulación en scala de las type classes de haskell

Tags: haskell, tipos, programación-funcional, scala

En un artículo que leí, escrito por Martin Odersky (["Unifying Functional and Object-Oriented Programming with Scala"](http://cacm.acm.org/magazines/2014/4/173220-unifying-functional-and-object-oriented-programming-with-scala/fulltext), Communications of the ACM, Vol. 57 No. 4, Pages 76-86), en las conclusiones indicaba lo siguiente:

> Another important abstraction mechanism in Scala is implicit parameters that let one emulate the essential capabilities of Haskell's type classes.

Entiendo cómo funcionan los argumentos implícitos en scala y conozco las *type classes* de haskell. Pero no entiendo bien cómo *"emular"* las *type classes* en scala usando argumentos implícitos.

¿Alguién tiene algún ejemplo en scala que pueda ilustrar este mecanismo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bueno, no conozco Scala suficiente como para dar una respuesta con certeza absoluta, pero sí conozco Haskell y uno de los mayores conceptos respecto a las clases de tipos ("type classes") es la **traducción a diccionarios** ("dictionary translation" o "dictionary passing").  Se trata de una técnica de implementación en la cual el compilador, dada una función cuyo tipo en el código fuente requiere una clase, traduce la función a un código intermedio en el cual las clases no existen.  Una función de fuente como la siguiente:

```
sameList :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
sameList [] [] = True
sameList [] _ = False
sameList (x:xs) (y:ys) = x == y && sameList xs ys
```

...se traduciría a una de código intermedio más parecida a esta:

```
data EqDict a = EqDict { equal :: a -> a - Bool } 

sameList :: EqDict a -> [a] -> [a] -> Bool
sameList _ [] [] = True
sameList _ [] _ = False
sameList (EqDict {equal = eq}) (x:xs) (y:ys) = 
  eq x y && sameList xs ys
```

...en la cual `EqDict a` es un **diccionario de clase**—una tabla de despacho que contiene los métodos de la clase `Eq` para el parámetro de tipo `a`.  Esto es un mecanismo de bajo nivel en los compiladores, y no una característica de Haskell propiamente dicho, pero no es difícil fijarse que armados con este concepto podemos tomar cualquier programa que usa clases de tipos y reformularlo sin ellas,  si escribimos nuestros propios "diccionarios" y los pasamos como argumentos a todas las funciones que los necesitan.  En el mundo de Haskell de vez en cuando recomienda alguien hace esto en vez de usar clases de tipos; [este artículo](http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/05/scrap-your-type-classes.html) (en inglés) me parece es el más conocido que recomienda esta técnica.

Igualmente, esto nos muestra que en un lenguaje funcional que no soporta las clases de tipo podemos sin embargo simularlas, construyendo nuestros propios diccionarios y pasándolos como argumentos explícitos a todas las funciones que los necesitan.  Podemos hacerlo el los lenguajes orientados a objetos también, por ejemplo en Java:

```
/**
 * Interfaz que corresponde a la clase `Eq` de Haskell.
 */
interface EqDict<A> {
    boolean equal(A x, A y);
}

public static <A> boolean sameList(EqDict<A> dict, List<A> xs, List<A> ys) {
    if (xs.size() != ys.size) return false;
    for (int i = 0; i < xs.size(); i++) {
      if (!dict.equal(xs.get(i), ys.get(i))) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

La desventaja es que las funciones se tornan más complicadas: en el ejemplo de arriba, la función `sameList` con clases the tipo toma dos argumentos, pero después de la traducción a diccionarios toma tres.  Sería muy enojoso repetir esto vez tras vez en nuestros programas fuente.

Y aquí es donde los argumentos implícitos entran en juego.  Con un tal mecanismo podemos usar esta técnica de los diccionarios pero sin tener que estar constantemente repitiéndolos en el programa.  Una función que requiere un diccionario (o dos, o tres, o cinco) los declara como argumentos implícitos, y así, cuando la usamos desde otra que también requiere los mismos argumentos implícitos el lenguaje automáticamente se encarga de comunicarlos.

Hay que notar sin embargo que los argumentos implícitos tienen ventajas y desventajas respecto a las clases de tipo.  La gran diferencia es que las clases de tipo garantizan que, dada la misma clase y el mismo tipo, siempre obtenemos el mismo diccionario.  Los argumentos implícitos, al contrario, permiten asociar diccionarios diferentes en distintas partes del programa al mismo tipo.  Este es un tema complicado en el cual no puedo entrar, pero el costo de la flexibilidad adicional de los argumentos implícitos es que facilita también la construcción de programas erróneos.

Comment: Lo primero, agradecerte muchísimo tu respuesta. Lamento no poder darla como válida por faltar algún ejemplo de scala.

He conseguido la referencia que ponen en el artículo: ["Type classes as objects and implicits"](https://ropas.snu.ac.kr/~bruno/papers/TypeClasses.pdf) de *Oliveira, B.C.d.S.* En este artículo también se comenta la conversión a diccionario de las clases de tipos y su conversión equivalente a programación orientada a objetos.

Con respecto a los problemas con argumentos implícitos, explica que, ante estas ambigüedades, siempre se emplea el que sea más *"específico"*.